# NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.readAllBytes()

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on a spring boot application which polls S3 bucket periodically using spring aws integration and processes the polled object from S3. While trying to read the processed object from another S3 bucket, i get the exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.readAllBytes()[B
    at com.app.controller.AppController.viewImage(AppController.java:79) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
```

It happens only in ec2 instances when i deploy as java application but does not occur in my local. Thinking that this might have been because of a class loading conflict with jars in amazon-linux ami, I tried deploying in ubuntu instance but the error repeats.

Just a snippet of my pom.xml which are relevant

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk -1</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.133</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-aws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Can someone help me fix this issue ? Also please let me know if any other detail is needed apart from the ones mentioned

Comment: The current version (1.11.478) of the [javadocs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html) doesn't show any method called `readAllBytes()` on that class.

Comment: but it works fine in my local deployment.

Comment: i think it has to do with jdk version

Comment: I mean I don't know what to tell you. I can't see your local setup. The S3 error is clearly saying "this method doesn't exist". A JDK mismatch is a distinct error that will say something along the lines of 'major minor release incompatible'.

Answer (score 5):

`realAllBytes` is a method of a parent class `InputStream`. This method has been added to `InputStream` since Java 9. You are probably using a lower jdk version at runtime